# Migrated infopath form does not find UDCX file for rest query when opened in the browser

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-rest-api, browser-compatibility, content-migration

We have migrated / moved some site, to a different Sharepoint location.

- Previous status: site was a root master site on a collection.
- Updated status: site is a subsite on a different site collection.

There is a Sharepoint list in the site, with a **custom infopath form**. The infopath form does make use of **.udcx connection file** in order to **perform different REST queries** against Sharepoint ( grab user information etc ).

Once the site was migrated / moved, infopath form could be **opened** in the **browser, however, the .udcx file was not found,** and therefore, REST query was NOT performed, leaving certain important form fields empty.

- The .udcx file location matches the one definied in the infopath, and it is
  fully accesible. However, infopath is not able to access the
  .udcx file.
- Form in the original site location works fine.
- Form in the new location works fine in preview mode ( infopath
  desktop app ). Browser mode does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found some people talking about bugs related with .[udcx files and after infopath forms moved to different sites.](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/t/30855.aspx)

I realized that, even the infopath designer was showing the .udcx filepath as the correct one, once [I exported the infopath manifest,](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/21103/73072.aspx) the infopath was searching for the .udcx at the root site within the site collection, what means, **a different location.**

```
<xsf2:xmlFileAdapterExtension ref="REST Web Service" isRest="yes">
       <xsf2:connectoid connectionLinkType="relative" source="Connections/rest.udcx" siteCollection="../../" name="REST Web Service"></xsf2:connectoid>
</xsf2:xmlFileAdapterExtension>
```

Therefore, all I had to do was to create the DataConnectionLibrary at root site collection level, and move my .udcx files over there.